# Showing a message for successful validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using asp.net MVC3 and enjoying the ease in which I can create client-side validation.

I may be missing something obvious, but is there a way in which I can set a 'validates successfully' property for each field, similar to how I can set an error message? I've noticed a field-validation-valid class is applied but I can't find any way to set any specific detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Floradu88 I didn't have any relevant code because I didn't know how to do it - the point of my question! Thanks anyway, Rick has actually now solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Overriding Unobtrusive Client Side Validation Settings in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/07/13/overriding-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-settings-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)

```
$(function() {
    var settngs = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
    var oldErrorFunction = settngs.errorPlacement;
    var oldSucessFunction = settngs.success;
    settngs.errorPlacement = function (error, inputElement) {
        //Do something here
        oldErrorFunction(error, inputElement);
    }
    settngs.success = function (error) {
        //Do something here
        oldSucessFunction(error);
    }
});
```